# how to select records from multiple table with max count value from one table using Linq in Asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables:
1. Tbl_Model,
2. Tbl_ModelImg,
3. Tbl_Category

I want to know how to fetch the records from these 3 tables using categoryId.

The single model may have multiple images, but I want to show all the products of that category with their images. The problem is I only want a single image in that view. So when a user clicks on that particular model, the details of that model and all its images will show on the next view.

The following query is working fine but it displays all the images with their model name. Means If a model has 4 images than on category details page it displays 4 items with the same name and different images.

Here is the model class :

```
     public class showdata
       {
        public Tbl_ModelImg tmi { get; set; }
        public Tbl_Model tm { get; set; }
        public Tbl_SubCategory tblsubcategory { get; set; }
        }
```

```
    
       public ActionResult Categorydetails(string sid)
            {
            var sId = Int64.Parse(new 
         StandardModule().Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(sid.ToString())));


            try
            {
                var query = (from c in db.Tbl_Model

                             join o in db.Tbl_ModelImg
                              on c.Model_Id equals o.Model_Id 
                             join d in db.Tbl_SubCategory on c.SubCategory_Id 
                             equals d.Id
                             where c.SubCategory_Id == sId
                             select new showdata()
                             {
                                 tm = c,
                                 tmi = o,
                                 tblsubcategory = d                  


                             }).OrderByDescending(d => d.tm.Id).ToList();


                    return View(query);
                }
```

Comment: When there are more images, what do you want to happen? Take first one (whatever "first" means), ignore all, something else?

Comment: Apparently a `Model` (= one item in tbl_model) has zero or more Images (from tbl_imgs). You wrote: "I want to show all the products of that category with their images. The problem is I only want a single image in that view." Is a product the same as row in `tbl_model`? If you have a product of a category, do you want it with all its images, or just with one of its images. And with which one? The newest? The largest? Don't matter which one?

Comment: @Hans & thank u for the reply sir,  what i want is to get all the records from tbl_Model and single record of that model(which have multiple images) from tbl_ModelImg

Comment: Sir @Harald thank u for the reply ,  tbl_Model contains records of the product...and tbl_ModelImg contains images of that product.. i just want to retrieve all the records from tbl_Model and single record of that model from tbl_ModelImg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the second line of the LINQ query with

```
join o in db.Tbl_ModelImg.GroupBy(m => m.Model_Id).Select(m => m.First())
```

The `GroupBy()` will group the items in `Tbl_ModelImg` by `Model_Id` and then the `Select()` will cut the contents of the resulting dataset down to just the first item in each group.

Once the `where` clause restricts your results to just those that items that join to the correct `SubCategory_Id` then you have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
                var query = (from c in db.Tbl_Model

                         join o in db.Tbl_ModelImg.GroupBy(m => m.Model_Id).Select(m 
                          => m.FirstOrDefault())
                          on c.Model_Id equals o.Model_Id 
                         join d in db.Tbl_SubCategory on c.SubCategory_Id equals d.Id
                         where c.SubCategory_Id == sId
                         select new showdata()
                         {
                             tm = c,
                             tmi = o,
                             tblsubcategory = d


                         }).OrderByDescending(d => d.tm.Id).ToList();
```